# Exceptions thrown during a Set operation in a Property are not being caught

Tags: c#, wpf, exception

When I attempt to run a function inside of a Set clause of a Property, any exception that would arise is never caught by my global exception handler. I don't understand why that happens. Here is my code (3 parts)

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel_();
    }
}

public class ViewModel_ : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ViewModel_()
    {
    }

    public string Texting
    {
        get { return _Texting; }
        set
        {
            _Texting = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Texting");
            throw new Exception("BAM!");
        }
    }
    private string _Texting;


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="TestExceptionHandling.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Texting,
        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</Grid>
```

App.xaml.cs (where global exception handler is)

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
    }

    void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("SOMETHING IS WRONG!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your output window while this runs. Does the error show up there? Binding properties don't blow up; they just don't bind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said by `Bob Horn`, binding properties don't blow up, if they are coming from target element(TextBox) i.e. from your View. Look into your output window, you will see message something like this -

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in WpfApplication4.exe
An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in WpfApplication4.exe but was not handled in user code
System.Windows.Data Error: 8 : Cannot save value from target back to source. BindingExpression:Path=Name; DataItem='VM' (HashCode=28331431); target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String') Exception:'System.Exception: BAM!
```

But, `try setting the same property from your ViewModel's constructor`, application definitely gonna blow up.

As a side note, this is not valid for all exception's, try doing this -

```
public string Texting
{
    get { return _Texting; }
    set
    {
        _Texting = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Texting");
        throw new StackOverflowException("BAM!");
    }
}
```

This will definitely caught up by your global exception handler since application can't be run in `StackOverflow` mode.

Comment: So any exception that would occur in the Set block of a binding property would be considered a binding error I take it? That would explain this. I guess I'll have to either have a try/catch or add a TextChanged event handler instead.